# Delegate touchstart events to click handler

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, mobile, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'd like to delegate all touchstart events to the defined click handler as a default for iPhone and other "Touch-Browsers". I came up with two approaches:

1) Extend the Ember.View to delegate all touchstart events to the click handler(s):

```
 Ember.View.reopen({
      touchStart: function(event) {
         return this.click(event);
      }
 });

 App.SomeView = Ember.View.extend({
      click: function(event) {
         console.log('should be fired for click and touchstart events');
      },          
 });
```

2) specify multiple action events in the (handlebars) template:

```
  <i {{action someAction on="click,touchStart"}} ></i>
```

Both approaches do not work. What am i missing? The Ember.Button is implemented [similar](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/lib/ember.js) (line 18625).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Ember.js version are you using? The following example works with the latest Ember.js `v1.0.0-pre2`, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/3c9bg/:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

Ember.View.reopen({
    touchStart: Ember.alias('click'),
    click: function() {
        console.log('clicki di click OR touchi di touch');
    }
});

Ember.View.create({
    elementId: 'leViewId',
    templateName: 'leViewTemplate'
}).append();

Ember.run.later(function() {
    Ember.$('#leViewId').trigger('touchstart');
}, 500);
Ember.run.later(function() {
    Ember.$('#leViewId').trigger('click');
}, 1000);
```

​

---

Registering multiple events via `<i {{action someAction on="click,touchStart"}} ></i>` doesn't work. If you want to handle more than 1 type of event, you should use a custom `Ember.View`.

Comment: thanks! your fiddle seems to work fine. Is Ember.alias a new method?

Comment: I updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3c9bg/3/ to allow testing with real devices. BTW it is actually working as expected with iphone mobile safari.

Comment: No, it's been available for a while now, it might have been undocumented. But theres documentation available, see http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.html#method_alias